# Firebase Function error and because of it Device to device Notification got Stuck

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I just got my hands on Firebase Functions and initially, everything was going correct, but now I am facing with the following Error. I am providing error and my codes below.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notification/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event =>{

  const user_id = event.params.user_id;
  const Notification = event.params.Notification;

  console.log('We have a Notification to send to :', user_id);

  if (!event.data.val()) {

    return console.console.log('A Notify has been deleted from the database :', notification_id);

  }

  const devicetoken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/{user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

  return devicetoken.then(result =>{

    const token_id = result.val();


    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title : "Follower Request",
        body: "You've received a new friend request",
        icon: "default"
      }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response =>{

      console.log('This was the notification Feature')

    });


  });


});
```

Below is the error which I am receiving in Firebase functions.

> Error: Registration token(s) provided to sendToDevice() must be a non-empty string or a non-empty array.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
>       at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:207:16)
>       at Messaging.validateRegistrationTokensType (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:589:19)
>       at Messaging.sendToDevice (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:210:14)
>       at devicetoken.then.result (/user_code/index.js:36:30)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

[Image of firebase function for above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjoMB.png)

[Image for providing an idea of how I have stored device_token_id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTsom.png)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: After you get the token with this statement, `const token_id = result.val()`, add a `console.log(`) statement to output `user_id` and `token_id`.  Most likely, the `token_id` is null for some user.  The log output will show you which one it is.

Comment: Okay.       I found a silly mistake of mine and on correction it started working fine. Thanks for ur reply.

Comment: Can u please tell me what was the mistake as I am also facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't use a templete tag `${}` at certain places

Also make sure there is a valid `device_token` stored in firebase for the user you're sending the notification.

The final code after implementing these changes and updating methods would be:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;

  console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', context.params.user_id);

  if(!change.after.val()) {
      return console.log('A Notification has been deleted from the database : ' + context.params.notification_id);
  }

  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

  return deviceToken.then(result =>  {

    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title : "Follower Request",
            body: "You've received a new friend request",
            icon: "default"
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
        return console.log('This was the notification Feature');  
    });

  });

});
```

To everyone referring to the *TVAC Studio*'s tutorial of ***Lapit Chat App***, I referred to this answer for the above changes https://stackoverflow.com/a/49746976/7549743