# TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined Firebase in Android

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, elasticsearch

I am using Google Cloud service in my Firebase project and service which I am using is Elasticsearch. So, I have successfully deployed the project on my Firebase project but the problem is whenever I am triggering my function,  then this comes as an error on my function log of firebase-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
at exports.indexPostsToElastic.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:13:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

This is my index.js file which I have written:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request-promise')
exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')

    .onWrite( event => {

    let postData = event.data.val();

    let post_id = event.params.post_id;


    console.log('Indexing post:', postData);


    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;


    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/post/' + post_id;


    let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';



    let elasticSearchRequest = {

        method: elasticSearchMethod,

        url: elasticSearchUrl,

        auth:   
            {

            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,

            password: elasticSearchConfig.password,

            },

            body: postData,

            json: true

     };


            return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => 
            {

                 console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);

                 return null;
      });
});
```

And this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined)

Comment: i did'nt get u.

Comment: click on the link above, and please read the answer there. As you can see in your package.json, you are using `"firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"` version 1.0.1 which brought lots of updated to cloud functions. Check the answer there and check this also: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

Comment: so what changes should i do in my code, i referred the above link but i did'nt understand properly. could you please help me out

Comment: You need to read the link in the comment above, change `.onWrite( event => {` into `.onWrite((change,context) => { let postData = change.after.val(); let post_id = context.params.post_id;`

Comment: Now also the same error is coming

Comment: nothing changed, again the same error and package.json is also showing "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"