# Why the following error when I deploy a function to firebase for realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-functions

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>       at exports.onDataAdded.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:5:28)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
>   [This is my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajEcg.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined)

Comment: Your question should include the source code that caused the error.  As it stands now, this error could be referring to any invalid use of a property called `val`.

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the uses of deprecated things.FCM has been updated from beta to 1.0.0. Now the difference can be seen in the following documentation-
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database