# Firebase cloud functions - Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

So here is the error;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:14:19)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:728:24
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

and here is my code:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {

  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification = context.params.notification;

  console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', user_id);

  if(!context.data.val()){
    return console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database:', notification_id);
  }

  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/deviceToken`).once('value');

  return deviceToken.then(result => {

    const token_id = result.val();

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title : "Friend Request",
        body : "You've receieved a new Friend Request",
        icon : "default"
      }
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

      console.log('This is the notification Feature');

    });

  });



});
```

Comment: You need to format the question properly, your code is not properly indented

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `context.data.val()` use `change.after.exists()`

Please test this function:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  const user_id = context.params.user_id;
  const notification = context.params.notification_id;
  console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', user_id);
  if (!change.after.exists()) { 
    console.log('A notification has been deleted from the database:', notification); 
    return null;
  }
  const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/deviceToken`).once('value');
  return deviceToken.then(result => {
    const token_id = result.val();
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Friend Request",
        body: "You've receieved a new Friend Request",
        icon: "default"
      }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {
      console.log('This is the notification Feature');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
const token_id = result.val();
```

try

```
const token_id = result.after.data();
```