# Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I try to learn how to send a notifications using a firebase functions. So I'm using this example code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.database.ref('/message').onWrite(event => {
const news = event.data.val();
     const payload = {notification: {
         title: 'New news',
         body: `${news.title}`
         }
     };
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("News",payload)
    .then(function(response){
         return console.log('Notification sent successfully:',response);
    }) 
    .catch(function(error){
         console.log('Notification sent failed:',error);
    });

});
```

but it gives me an error:
`Cannot read property 'val' of undefined`
I've been looking for a solution, tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746905/firebase-typeerror-cannot-read-property-val-of-undefined), but still no-go...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `console.log(event)` to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I suspect you are using a very old tutorial or sample code.  I suggest following the documentation instead for up to date descriptions of how the APIs work.

Comment: For specific instructions how to migrate your code to the 1.0 and later versions, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are not using the syntax as specified in the documentation.

Refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) documentation.

Anyways, as I see in the documentation linked above, your code should be :

```
exports.sendAdminNotification = functions.database.ref('/message')
    .onWrite((change, context) => { 
        console.log(change);
        // Do something with change or context
    });
```